# How to make Whisper AI (speech-to-text) use GPU on Intel Macbook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, gpu, intel, macos

I just installed Whisper AI to transcribe voice to text. Apparently it does support running on GPU, which should be much more efficient than using the CPU, but I fail to do that. I have read this thread on Github

https://github.com/openai/whisper/pull/382

and I have tried the command line options `--device cuda` and `--device mps`. I have also installed py-pytorch from MacPorts but everytime I run Whisper I just get a message that it is using the CPU.

How do I make Whisper using the GPU on my Macbook Pro 16 " (Intel) with and AMD Radeon Pro 5500M 4 GB GPU?

Comment: CUDA is entirely an NVidia structure.

Comment: @Tetsujin Is there a corresponding AMD technology/standard?

Comment: Effectively, no.

Comment: MPS (Metal Performance Shaders) is going to be your only viable option on any recent macOS (regardless of Intel vs. Apple Silicon, and regardless of GPU).  As for how to get it to use the GPU: you'll probably have to install some additional Python libraries— Apple has general instructions here: https://developer.apple.com/metal/pytorch/ . That may not do it for Whisper specifically; you may need to hack their Python code a bit to make sure it's using `torch.device("mps")` and is using data types MPS supports— programming any non-Python programmer should be able to hack in. Or it may just work.

Comment: @SlippD.Thompson The installation seemed to work fine but it doesn't work. Error message: `loc("mps_multiply"("(mpsFileLoc): /AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/810eba08-405a-11ed-86e9-6af958a02716/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/MetalPerformanceShadersGraph/mpsgraph/MetalPerformanceShadersGraph/Core/Files/MPSGraphUtilities.mm":228:0)): error: input types 'tensor<1x768x3000xf16>' and 'tensor<1xf32>' are not broadcast compatible
LLVM ERROR: Failed to infer result type(s).
zsh: abort      ~/Library/Python/3.9/bin/whisper --device mps --language Swedish` (continues in the next comment)

Comment: `(base) db@16 ~ % /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/resource_tracker.py:216: UserWarning: resource_tracker: There appear to be 1 leaked semaphore objects to clean up at shutdown
  warnings.warn('resource_tracker: There appear to be %d '`

Comment: @d-b Looks similar to issues listed in that pull request you linked— the first error message seems to be trying to use an f16 (16-bit float, aka `half`) and an f32 (32-float, aka `float`) together, so that doesn't seem right.  I think I read on that PR there was some stuff about how to fix type issues.  Sorry, can't help more; I'm afraid you'll have to research issues and/or use basic Python programming skills to just fix or work around each error you encounter.